# MVC - where to put blitting data

Tags: actionscript

I'm currently in the process of building a game using the MVC pattern. I am also using full blitting for the first time and have come to a cross roads in my code. I'm questioning where the data for the blitting should go (ie spritesheet, rectangle data etc). I feel like it should be part of the Model but it seems a bit clumsy, when drawing the pixel data in the View, to keep referring to the model for everything (ie model.canvas.copyPixels(model.spriteSheet, model.rectsArray[model.index], model.point) ).

Has anyone had any experience setting up MVC for use with blitting? Would this be the best set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One the one hand, graphics data should clearly go in the view. However, it's often also important for things like bounds checking, collision shapes, etc. Therefore I advise to encapsulate the graphics data in a class/module with two interfaces.

- One interface provides access to just the graphics in can be given to the view.
- The other provides access to the data derived from the graphics and can be given to the model.